# How do I remove a ceiling speaker cover?

Tags: removal, speakers, cover

I have speakers in my ceiling and I need to get the covers off to check the settings. I've tried pulling them with my fingernails and a plastic knife but no luck so far. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These look like Polk Audio speakers to me - I have the same ones.

From page 12 of the [user manual](http://www.polkaudio.com/downloads/manual/RC6s_MN.pdf), they suggest a paperclip.   I realize yours are square, there are few different models.

> If the speaker is already in the wall, carefully hook the grille with
>   a bent paper clip and pull it gently away from the frame

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the speaker brand, but I'm 99.9% sure it's going to be magnetically held. Now that you know that you'll go peel it right off. Be careful you don't bend it, they can be very thin.

How do know the speaker has adjustments?

Continued:

Hum! I was involved in a commercial auditorium theater system installation and the ceiling and cabinet mounted speakers all had flat ribbon magnets on the entire front perimeter of the enclosures. And the very thin, light weight grills snapped to it as tight as could be. I see for the Polks that @Steven have, only the perforated inner grill is friction held for its entire perimeter to the permanently installed outer frame providing a similar firm and continuous attachment. But I would think you'd recall that from when you had the one off. I would also think that some sort of a clip or spring loaded mechanism would be the least desirable method possibly allowing the grill to vibrate and make sounds of its own, but maybe that's it. Try pushing on the grill on each edge and see if there's any movement. I guess the other possibility is that the painter just finished painting the ceiling and put the grills right back up on the wet paint.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen a speaker with a magnetic grille, although I don't have much experience with ceiling-mounted speakers. What makes you so confidant?

Comment: One of the speakers in the ceiling had the grill already coming off so it was easy to take off with fingers. The others are stuck fast. So I know what's under it and that it's not magnetic. I should have mentioned that in the question but didn't think it relevant. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the magnetic type, they are out there. Most of the ones I seen are held in by pressure fit.

To remove the ones you have you will need an item small enough to fit inside the holes with a tight bend in it to serve as a hook to start to pull at the corners. A dental tool has hard enough steel in it to pull with out straightening out.
You need to ease a corner out just a little then pull out a little farther down the edge till you get to the other corner. Work all the way around like this a little at a time.  Say about 1/8" out. If you pull it out too much at one time you will deform the grill and it will be really difficult to reinstall. By the time you go around the second time it will come free.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a 3" putty knife: carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Polk Audio in ceiling speakers as well. I banged the top of my ladder into the grill and dented it. It was very easy to see and very annoying to look at. I read the posts that people suggested and were Helpful. However, I had already thrown out my families old dental instruments as I am moving into a new home.

I did however find a fishing Lure which was mean for some big time fish.It has a very sharp tip (obviously). All I basically had to do was take a pair of vice-grips and bend the lure so that the hook can easily fit in and the lure manipulated without hitting the ceiling.

I was pleasantly surprised to see how well this worked. No I don't have a blemish and its nice to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip kept.deforming. Did it near the edge and got it to pop the edge up. Had to hold the clip near the base of it entering the grill to help support the clip.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pulling down on the grill, starting at the corners with a dental like tool.  It worked perfectly.  I have 20 year old Klipsch that look very similar to the pictured speaker.  I needed to paint the covers.  I never knew how yellow they were til I painted.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try this YouTube video. It seems to make the most sense.

https://youtu.be/Fk0xqr9dEsQ?si=cB6bwM9DdEmmPEHA

Comment: Link answers don't go well here. they often disappear from the sites that post them.