# How to remove in wall speaker grill/frame

Tags: home-theater, speakers

I tried all the suggestions in the following question to no avail (no accepted answer)

[How do I remove a ceiling speaker cover?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41559/how-do-i-remove-a-ceiling-speaker-cover)

I also watched several YT videos that so far haven't provided any additional insight.

How do I remove the following speaker grill and/or frame so that I can cleanly paint the walls? We just moved in to a new house (built 2014), I have no manuals and what I have tried so far hasn't worked (putty knife, paper clip equivalent, etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The answers to the question you linked are correct. You have hidden connections that will require that you pull down on the frame to release it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a ceiling speaker cover?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41559/how-do-i-remove-a-ceiling-speaker-cover)

Comment: How much force should be required? I tried the answers from the other question, but perhaps more force is required than I would otherwise expect?

Comment: Enough and less then will break it. I mean, it's the only way it's coming off (how else would it be attached?) Maybe try (Google yourself please) a "Auto Trim Removal Tool" or use a small flat bar, a butter knife, or sim to get in between the grill edge and the sheet rock. Work around the edge a few times and slowly work it off.

Comment: Try looking up the _installation_ instructions for a variety of different brands/models of in-ceiling speakers to get an idea of how they're installed. They're probably all quite similar, but knowing how they go in will help you understand how they come out.

Comment: @Ack I tried again with a really small flathead screwdriver in the corners and that allowed me to eventually get it off after going around all corners once to "start" it and then was able to remove on a second pass after. The paper clip/fishing line suggested in the other question's answers definitely did not work.

Comment: Great! Will you post your comment as an answer to your question then accept it as the answer? This will help future people looking for a solution, much like you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some speakers the grill part, *not the bezel or frame of the grill assembly*, but the actual grill with the small holes in it is pressed into the bezel/frame.

You take a tool with a point small enough to fit in the holes, or even a very small screwdriver, and you gently pry the grill up and out of the bezel/frame. You want to try and get a hold of the side of the grill just before it enters the bezel.  You need to be careful and not try to pull to much out at once and bend the grill. Work your way out in both directions from one corner until you can get that corner free.

On my JBL control 5 this is what i have to do, and your grill material look exactly the same as my JBL's.  There is a pliable mastic in the groove that "holds" the grill in place, once you get one corner up you can work it  little by little around the grill.

If this works then there should be mounting screws visible to remove the bezel, or the speaker may be attached to the bezel and the whole unit comes out.

To reassemble you just push the grill back into the groove in the bezel.

**I do not know if this how your speaker is constructed so proceed with caution.**

All that said, If you can not figure it out, you can use painters tape and carefully tape around the bezel, paint and remove the tape before the paint dries.

Comment: Went with a very small screwdriver in the corners of the grill, and after a couple "passes" finally got it to come out enough to actually detach the grill. Thanks! I had originally tried the putty knife, paperclip etc. suggested in the other question, but this approach worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and figured out that the covers were just magnetic and using a small screwdriver, I was easily able to pop them off.

Comment: Are your speakers the same model as the OPs? If not, this isn't particularly helpful, especially since he figured it out 3 years ago...